# Creating 10 categorical and 10 continuous random variables and save them as a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, simulation

I would like to create a data frame with 10 categorical and 10 continuous random variables. I can do it using the following loop.

```
   p_val=rbeta(10,1,1)   #10 probabilities
    n=20
    library(truncnorm)
    mu_val=rtruncnorm(length(p_val),0,Inf, mean = 100, sd=5)#rnorm(length(p))
    d_mat_cat=matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = length(p))
    d_mat_cont= matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = length(p))
      for ( j in 1:length(p)){
        d_mat_cat[,j]=rbinom(n,1,p[j]) #Binary RV
        d_mat_cont[,j]=rnorm(n,mu_val[j]) #Cont. RV
      }
    d_mat=cbind(d_mat_cat, d_mat_cont)
```

Any alternative options are appreciated.

Comment: What is the question/issue? Is this code not working? Do you get an error message or incorrect result?

Comment: Can you explain in words how you are generating these, and why you'd like an alternative?

Comment: The code is working. But I want to know if I can do it quickly with alternative options

Comment: @Suren If I need to generate a very large number of variable then this loop may take more time, that's why I am looking for alternatives if  anyone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rbinom` is vectorized over `prob`, and `rnorm` is vectorized over `mean`, so you can use this:

```
cbind(
  matrix(rbinom(n * length(p_val), size = 1, prob = p_val), 
         ncol = length(p_val), byrow = TRUE),
  matrix(rnorm(n * length(mu_val), mean = mu_val),
         ncol = length(mu_val), byrow = TRUE)
)
```

We can be a little clever with `rep` to make the call much cleaner:

```
p_val = c(0, 0.5, 1)
mu_val = c(1, 10, 100)
n = 4

## 
matrix(
  c(
    rbinom(n * length(p_val), size = 1, prob = rep(c(0, .5, 1), each = n)),
    rnorm(n * length(mu_val), mean = rep(c(1, 10, 100), each = n))
  ),
  nrow = n,
)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]       [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
# [1,]    0    1    1  1.1962718 9.373595 100.1739
# [2,]    0    0    1 -0.1854631 9.574706 100.0725
# [3,]    0    1    1  3.4873697 9.447363 100.1345
# [4,]    0    1    1  2.8467450 9.700975 101.3178
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `sapply` to run `rbinom` and `rnorm` and `cbind` the data.

```
cbind(sapply(p_val, rbinom, n = n, size = 1), sapply(mu_val, rnorm, n = n))
```